# is there domain option for menuitem definition on xml on Odoo

Tags: xml, menuitem, odoo-13

i setup an Odoo 13 CE as a multi-companies environment, there are five companies.

because not all companies using the same workflow, therefore, i hope some functions defined on menu they are company specific is only visible to the specific company, instead of everything are same, so the menu will be concise without confusing.

how can i make a self-defined menuitem only visible to user based on some conditions?

for example, can i define the domain of a menuitem so it only visible to
[image]

the above code having error upon my custom module installed.

if control the visibility of a function not possible, is there another way i can control this on Odoo?